# DataTables plugin changes header & footer background color accidentally

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm using DataTables jQuery plugin to display a grid. I have a modal popup that changes the background color of the entire form and, accidentally, the background color of the before mentioned table's header & footer background color. This is the code used to initialize the popup:

```
var modalBackground = $("#modalBackground");
var Notifications_ArchiveHolder = $("#Notifications_ArchiveHolder");
var Notifications_ShowArchivePopupHolder = $("#Notifications_ShowArchivePopupHolder");
var ArchiveURL = "@Url.Action("Archive")";
var ShowArchiveUrl = "@Url.Action("ShowArchive")";

function ShowArchivePopup() {        
    $.get(ArchiveURL, function (content) {
        if (Notifications_ArchiveHolder.html().length <= 10) {
            Notifications_ArchiveHolder.html(content);
            InitArchivePopup();
        }
    })
}

function InitArchivePopup() {       
    modalBackground.show();
    //set up positon
    var h = $(window).height();
    var w = $(window).width();
    var hh = Notifications_ArchiveHolder.height();
    var hw = Notifications_ArchiveHolder.width();
    var posx = (h / 2) - 100;
    var posy = (w / 2) - 200;
    Notifications_ArchiveHolder.css("position", "fixed");
    Notifications_ArchiveHolder.css("top", posx);
    Notifications_ArchiveHolder.css("left", posy);

    Notifications_ArchiveHolder.show();
    $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
}
```

The popup is hosted in the following div:

```
<div id="Notifications_ArchiveHolder" style="background-color: white; display: none; z-index: 9999;"></div>
```

and this is the div who's css class makes the entire background gray and also changes my table's header & footer background color:

```
<div id="modalBackground" class="graphicScreen" style="display: none; position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px;"></div>

 .graphicScreen
{
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 50px;
background-color: #878786;
z-index: 9990;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
filter: alpha(opacity=30);
-moz-opacity: 0.3;
-khtml-opacity: 0.3;
opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Any idea why this happens and how to prevent it ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem (with some help): I was referencing jQuery-UI.css in the modal popup, and this was causing an overwrite of the properties of the data table. very curious..